# What’s wrong with my Aloe Vera?

Tags: succulents, aloe

I got this little aloe plant from a succulent subscription service and when it arrived a few of its leaves looked a little yellow... I thought maybe it had a rough transport and/or was overwatered, so since I got it And reported it Around a month ago I’ve watered it twice. I use Bonsai Jacks gritty mix so it’s super well drained! I keep it right under a grow light With my other succulents since we don’t have great window space! Any ideas what’s up with it? The second time I watered it was earlier today because I noticed the tips seemed pretty dried out and figured it could maybe use a little since the 3ish weeks ago when I last watered...[image]